# Is it possible to create a complicated sql query for this scenario?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

[image]
[image]

Is it possible to create a SQL query that will return this result set? here 'NA' means not available. Your help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Here are sample data for testing, which Sander was kind enough to transcribe from my images:

```
create  table CurrentProduct
(
    CategoryName nvarchar(20),
    Productname nvarchar(20)
)
GO

insert into CurrentProduct (CategoryName, Productname) values
('Cat1', 'Prod1'),
('Cat1', 'Prod2'),
('Cat2', 'Prod3'),
('Cat5', 'Prod4'),
('Cat5', 'Prod5')
GO

create  table PreviousProduct
(
    CategoryName nvarchar(20),
    Productname nvarchar(20)
)
GO

insert into PreviousProduct (CategoryName, Productname) values
('Cat1', 'Prod1'),
('Cat1', 'Prod2'),
('Cat4', 'Prod3'),
('Cat5', 'Prod4')
GO

create  table FutureProduct
(
    CategoryName nvarchar(20),
    Productname nvarchar(20)
)
GO

insert into FutureProduct (CategoryName, Productname) values
('Cat1', 'Prod1'),
('Cat1', 'Prod2'),
('Cat4', 'Prod3'),
('Cat5', 'Prod4')
GO
```

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2029983) Why tag 2 unsupported versions of SQL Server, one of which is **completely** unsupported? What have **you** tried and why didn't it work? Someone with 800 reputation should know why images of data are frowned upon as well, and why including your attempt(s) is so important. Take the time to help us help you. Note, as well, the only question you ask here is *"Is it possible to create a SQL query that will return this result set?"*; the answer to that question is very likely "Yes".

Comment: Please post text instead of pictures. Also, there is no way to link the second Cat1 line from CurrentProduct to the second Cat1 line of PreviousProduct (it cannot be distinguished from the first line in PreviousProduct).

Comment: If you can't give answer don't give downvote because i don't think this question is trivial , it's my current task problem.

Comment: There is no negative feedback here, @Humayoun_Kabir . If you see downvotes as negative feedback, then you are misunderstanding them. A Downvote is to show that the person that made the downvote feels that the question is not helpful, or lacks research, and is to let *other* users viewing the site know that. It is not a "feedback" device.

Comment: @Larnu , I have edited the title. yes i mean downvote. no problem you can downvoted me , would you please give the solution if you can.

Comment: @Sander we all know picture is better than thousand of theory.

Comment: Sure we all love to type the sample again based on your images.

Comment: No, pictures are not worth a 1000 words, not only do they take up more space and are header to read, but more importantly we are unable to copy and paste the data out for testing. You can post the same data, but as formatted text. The easier you make it for us, the more likely you will get a fast answer. DDL/DML as show in the answer it even better.

Comment: *"please give the solution if you can*" Sure, when you actually address the point I made in my [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63483873/need-help-to-create-a-t-sql-query-on-this-complex-scenario#comment112258934_63483873), I'll be more than happy to.

Comment: @Humayoun_Kabir the data from pictures cannot be copy-pasted in a coding editor. You made me type them myself...

Comment: And although it's great of you to do that for them, @Sander , it is really the OP's responsibility to do it. Unfortunately they'll now continue to think that it's "ok" to make others transcribe what they could easily copy and paste... Along with post conflicting tags, show no effort, or research, or ask a *actual* question. All the things the community expects from a *good* question.

Comment: @Sander I am really sorry , I didn't understand the copy-paste situation. If i would know that before i will definately give that. Give me some time , i am giving test data.

Comment: Also, on different note, the *real* problem appears to be your design here. Having a "Previous", "current" and "future" table isn't a normalised design. there should be one table, which has a column to denote the "presence(?)" of the row.

Comment: @Larnu For some restriction I could not give real table name , sorry for that also.

Comment: Table names give no PII, or company, data away, @Humayoun_Kabir . Not unless the objects are quite poorly named. :) I have no problems with listing of a bunch of the tables in my production databases, as they are meaningless on their own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the last 2 tables can be joined on CategoryName *and* ProductName (otherwise there is no unique link between the tables)...
You can use a [common table expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) with [`UNION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql) to gather all the category names.

**Sample data**

```
declare @CurrentProduct table
(
    CategoryName nvarchar(5),
    ProductName nvarchar(5)
);
insert into @CurrentProduct (CategoryName, ProductName) values
('Cat1', 'Prod1'),
('Cat1', 'Prod2'),
('Cat2', 'Prod3'),
('Cat5', 'Prod4'),
('Cat5', 'Prod5');

declare @PreviousProduct table
(
    CategoryName nvarchar(5),
    ProductName nvarchar(5)
);
insert into @PreviousProduct (CategoryName, ProductName) values
('Cat1', 'Prod1'),
('Cat1', 'Prod2'),
('Cat4', 'Prod3'),
('Cat5', 'Prod4');

declare @FutureProduct table
(
    CategoryName nvarchar(5),
    ProductName nvarchar(5)
);
insert into @FutureProduct (CategoryName, ProductName) values
('Cat1', 'Prod1'),
('Cat1', 'Prod2'),
('Cat4', 'Prod3'),
('Cat5', 'Prod4');
```

**Solution**

```
with cte_cat as
(
    select cp.CategoryName from @CurrentProduct cp
        union
    select pp.CategoryName from @PreviousProduct pp
        union
    select fp.CategoryName from @FutureProduct fp
)
select  c.CategoryName,
        coalesce(cp.ProductName, 'NA') as 'CurrentProd',
        coalesce(pp.ProductName, 'NA') as 'PrevProd',
        coalesce(fp.ProductName, 'NA') as 'FtrProd'
from cte_cat c
left join @CurrentProduct cp
    on  cp.CategoryName = c.CategoryName
outer apply (   select top 1 pp.ProductName
                from @PreviousProduct pp
                where pp.CategoryName = c.CategoryName
                  and pp.ProductName = coalesce(cp.ProductName, pp.ProductName) ) pp
outer apply (   select top 1 fp.ProductName
                from @FutureProduct fp
                where fp.CategoryName = c.CategoryName
                  and fp.Productname = coalesce(cp.Productname, fp.ProductName) ) fp;
```

**Result**

```
CategoryName CurrentProd PrevProd FtrProd
------------ ----------- -------- -------
Cat1         Prod1       Prod1    Prod1
Cat1         Prod2       Prod2    Prod2
Cat2         Prod3       NA       NA
Cat4         NA          Prod3    Prod3
Cat5         Prod4       Prod4    Prod4
Cat5         Prod5       NA       NA
```

Comment: This certainly works, though 2 scans (with a `UNION`) on each table seems a little expensive here. This could likely perform better with a `UNION ALL` and then unpivoting the data.